# Can I make a Neural Network output matrices with irregular shapes?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to have the Neural Network output 3 different matrices, two being of shape(8,1) and the other of (12,1) shape. Is there any way I can do this with Keras?

Comment: `keras` & `neural-network` are arguably more appropriate tags here than `python` (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, add multiple layers with the desired shapes connected to the penultimate layer. Then pass these output layers as a list to `model.compile(..., outputs=[out1, out2, ...])`.
You do need to be using the [functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) for this and not the `Sequential` model.